# Comparison table for comparing products

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm attempting to create a comparison table to compare products depending on the add-ons they have. To grab the data and filter it I'm using LINQ To SQL.

Table's Layout (cut short):

> ```
> Products Table  
> ID
> Name
> CategoryID
> ProductAddons
>
> Category Table
> ID
> Name
>
> ProductAddon Table
> ID
> Amount 
> AddonID
> ProductID
>
> Addon Table
> ID
> Name
> ```

Example Data:

> ```
> Products
>
> ID      Name      CategoryID
> 1       Product1  1   
> 2       Product2  1 
> 3       Product3  1 
>
> Categories
>
> ID      Name
> 1       Category1
>
> ProductAddons
>
> ID      Amount      AddonID      ProductID
> 1       1           1            1
> 2       2           2            1 
> 3       1           3            1
> 4       2           1            2
> 5       3           2            2
> 6       1           2            3
> 7       1           3            3
>
> Addons
>
> ID      Name
> 1       Addon1
> 2       Addon2
> 3       Addon3
> ```

Currently I have this:

```cs
var addons = (from s in Products
              where s.Category.Name == "Category1"
              orderby s.ProductAddons.Count descending
              let adds = from a in s.ProductAddons
                         orderby a.Addon.Name
                         select new { Name = a.Addon.Name, Amount = a.Amount }
              select adds).ToList();

var compare = from c in addons
              let has = from z in addons.First().Union(addons.First().Except(c))
                      let add = (from a in c
                                 where a.Name == z.Name
                                 select a.Amount).FirstOrDefault()
                      select new { Name = z.Name, Amount = add }
              select has;

var compileResults = from c in addons.First()
                     let adds = from s in compare
                             let y = (from a in s
                                      where a.Name.Contains(c.Name)
                                      select a.Amount).First()
                             select y
                     select new { Addon = c.Name, Amounts = adds };
```

This would return (3 products, 3 Add-ons):

> ```
> Addon          Amounts
>
> Addon1         1
>                2
>                0
>
> Addon2         2
>                3
>                1
>
> Addon3         1
>                0
>                1
> ```

I can then loop through the results to build my compare table, which works fine. But to me the LINQ looks somewhat messy. Would there be a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Do you have some sample data that would produce those results that you could share with us?  Your query is _very_ complicated, much more complicated than it probably has to be and it's hard to make sense of it.  "somewhat messy" is a _huge_ understatement.

Comment: Hi Jeff. I've added the table layouts and sample data. The table layouts are set in stone and cannot be changed.

Comment: You say you're using LINQ to SQL, but there's an Entity Framework tag on the question. They're really two different technologies any may (or may not) matter in getting a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like what you want is some sort of outer join.  I think this should work for you:

```
var categoryFilter = "Category1";
var query =
    from addon in dc.Addons
    select new
    {
        Addon = addon.Name,
        Amounts =
            from product in dc.Products
            where product.Category.Name == categoryFilter
            join productAddon in dc.ProductAddons
                on new { AddonId = addon.Id, ProductId = product.Id }
                equals new { productAddon.AddonId, productAddon.ProductId }
                into pas
            from productAddon in productAddons.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select (int?)productAddon.Amount ?? 0,
    };
```

Comment: Where does this order by the add-on count in a descending fashion? I've been wrestling with it myself to no end and can't get it to work properly in a single query.

Comment: This assumes the order provided by the context.  No additional ordering was made on the addons.  Though that could easily be added by including `orderby addon.Id`.